# How to store the result of a subquery in a variable in cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, environment-variables

Here's my bat file:

```
@echo off
 for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ('type C:\LocalSecrets\Depolyment.csv ^| findstr "%DomainName%"') do call :parcsv %%a
 goto :EOF

:parcsv
 echo "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4"
 set x_cola=%~1
 set x_colb=%~2
 set x_colc=%~3
 set x_cold=%~4
 goto :EOF
```

What I want to do is to store that `type C:\LocalSecrets\Depolyment.csv ^| findstr "%DomainName%"` in a local variable and then call the `for` on that variable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET MYCMD=findstr "%DomainName%" c:\localsecrets\deployment.csv
for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ('%MYCMD%') do  ....
```

Please note that findstr can take the filename as 2nd parameter which avoids the use of the pipe, which is problematic when storing commands in environment vars.

PS.
I presume you only want parcsv called for the first occurrence of %DomainName% in the file.
Otherwise the CALL construct makes no sense at all.

Comment: It did not work. Simply `echo %Line%` and you see that the line is not executed. Rather, it's a simple script that has been stored in that `MYCMD` variable to be executed later. What I want is to execute that code, and only save the result of its execution in that variable.

Comment: In Linux, we simply use `export var_name=$(cat /etc/os-release)` and it's called subshell.

Comment: @AliEXE You were not clear in your question that you wanted the result of the query. I read it as if you just wanted to store the command itself. Besides that: Why do you need this? In a Unix environment storing arbitrary output in a environment var is easy, but CommandPrompt is very different and environment var's in CMD are not suited for multi-line content. Some concepts don't translate well from Unix shells to CMD. Using a tmp-file to hold the content is probably much easier and more efficient.